# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting find multiple items

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to write conditional formatting to find a double quote. I have tried various techniques, but it doesn't seem to work

```
Sub CondForm()
     With Range("A19:AG10000")
       .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(""|"",A19)))>0,SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",A19)))>0)"
       .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False
       .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = -16776961
       .FormatConditions(2).Font.Bold = True
 End With
End Sub
```

This generates a correct looking formula
    `=AND(SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND("|",A19)))>0,SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND("",A19)))>0)`
But it only triggers when the 'pipe' value is entered. If I take out the first conditional and just use `=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND("""",A19)))>0` it also works. Does anyone know how to look for BOTH conditions?

Comment: I know a simple answer is just to put in two separate conditional formulas, and I may do that, but I was just curious if there was a way to search for both in one statement.

Comment: it should be `""""` in the formula and `""""""""` (8 `"`) in VBA, or `CHAR(34)` in both https://exceljet.net/formula/double-quotes-inside-a-formula

Comment: Wow, eight double quotes! Thanks, this worked for me.